# Selecting the first tag of a certain type in multiple levels of other tags

Tags: html, css, selector

I need to apply a style to every subtag of a certain type inside a tag of a certain type but I don't know the right CSS selector combination.

For example, in this markup, I want to select all the tags that say `Select me` and turn them blue, but not any other tags:

```
<i>Don't select me</i>

<div>
    <p>
        <i>Select me</i>
    </p>
    <p>
        <i>Don't select me</i>
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <p>
        <b>Don't select me</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        <i>Select me</i>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
div i:first-of-type {
    color: blue;
}
```

but it selects all the `i` tags inside the `div`.

I have also tried

```
div p:first-of-type i:first-of-type {
    color: blue;
}
```

but obviously that won't get the second `Select me` because it's in the second `p` tag.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/eEHvp/

Comment: Any reason your not using a class?

Comment: @KevinBowersox the markup is generated by javascript and would be cumbersome to check if it were the first type generated to conditionally add a class.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a CSS selector

Comment: @Itay it boils down to "select the first `i` tag inside a `div`." That seems imminently doable doesn't it?

Comment: @Kal I'm not a CSS savant, but I agree with Itay.  I don't think this is possible considering the `i` element will always be the first element within the `p` tag.

Comment: @Kal but `i` is not a direct child of `div`

Comment: @KevinBowersox yeah, I said "inside a `div`".

Comment: It's doable with JS or another class, but not with CSS3. The `first-of-type` and `first-child` selectors are relative to the direct parent

Comment: @Kal Hopefully someone comes along and proves us wrong.  But I would just do the work in the js by adding a class if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is impossible with CSS3 [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

[first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) and [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) etc. are relative to their **direct** parent.